# Tags in MS Word like tags in web blogs. How?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a possibility to create tags in Word documents like tags in web blogs? For example, I have such a text in my Word document:

```
Rabbits live in forests.
tags: rabbit

Rabbit is in Alice in Wonderland book.
tags: rabbit, alice_in_wonderland
```

So when choosing "rabbit" word I can find all sections in my document I write about rabbits.

I tried to use Word bookmarks but it doesn't allow to link one bookmark to more that one word even though it is one and the same word. How to implement such functionality?

Comment: Word has [Smart Tags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284927), but I don't think those will help here. Perhaps some sort of hidden text or field codes?

Comment: You can tag the document as whole in the Properties section.

Comment: You are not by any chance trying to use a Word processor for database tasks? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In Word 2010 the Index feature, on the `References` tab, allows you to tag words and create an index which shows all the pages the word appears on.

Here are detailed instructions how to [create and update an index](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-an-index-and-update-an-index-HP001226499.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a manual procedure, the simplest is to use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. If you put "tag: rabbit" in the field you'll access quickly to all the occurrences. In fact, you don't even need to add tag if the word you're looking for is in the text. If you insist to use tags, put them in comments boxes. That way you can hide them as you wish, and the search function still works.

Comment: This won't work with multiple tags because the second tag doesn't start with `tag=`.